# Building a loop in R to scan all files in a directory

Tags: r, for-loop, statistics

I guess to create a better example here, say I have the file mtcars and what I did with it was to export every one of its rows into independent files and place them into empty directories, as such:

```
for(i in 1:nrow(mtcars))
write.table(mtcars[i,], file=paste(“mtcars”, as.character(i), ".txt",
sep=""), row.names=FALSE, sep="\t")
```

What I want to do is to build a loop so that I can scan a folder, which includes all rows and column names and create a new data frame.

Here's what I have so far and I think it only does columns but not rows.

```
myfiles<-list.files()
for (file in mayflies) {
  if (file=="myrows.txt") {
    myrows <- read.table(file, header=TRUE, sep="\t")
  } else {
    tdataset <- read.table(file, header=TRUE, sep="\t")
    mydataset <- cbind(mydataset, tdataset)
    rm(tdataset)
  }
}
row.names(meditates) <- myrows
```

How can I make my results in the above code, make a folder out of it, scan all rows and columns, and eventually create a new data frame with the first set of code listed above?  If you can explain some of the logic to me that would be incredibly helpful.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not entirely sure what you are asking---Do you want to recreate your original `data.frame`?

Using your minimal example:

```
for (i in 1:nrow(mtcars))
    write.table(mtcars[i,], file=paste("mtcars", as.character(i), ".txt", sep=""), row.names=FALSE, sep="\t")
```

The following code will reconstruct `mtcars`:

```
files <- list.files(pattern = ".txt$")           # List all .txt files
rows <- lapply(files, read.table, header = TRUE) # Read the files into list
res <- do.call(rbind, rows)                      # combine the data.frame
head(res)
#   mpg cyl  disp  hp drat   wt  qsec vs am gear carb
#1 21.0   6 160.0 110 3.90 2.62 16.46  0  1    4    4
#2 19.2   6 167.6 123 3.92 3.44 18.30  1  0    4    4
#3 17.8   6 167.6 123 3.92 3.44 18.90  1  0    4    4
#4 16.4   8 275.8 180 3.07 4.07 17.40  0  0    3    3
#5 17.3   8 275.8 180 3.07 3.73 17.60  0  0    3    3
#6 15.2   8 275.8 180 3.07 3.78 18.00  0  0    3    3
```

Is that what you want? If not, please explain what you want as the output.

**EDIT**: As a loop:

```
files <- list.files(pattern = ".txt$")           # List all .txt files
res <- NULL
for (file in files) {
  row <- read.table(file, header = TRUE)
  res <- rbind(res, row)
}
head(res)
#    mpg cyl  disp  hp drat   wt  qsec vs am gear carb
# 1 21.0   6 160.0 110 3.90 2.62 16.46  0  1    4    4
# 2 19.2   6 167.6 123 3.92 3.44 18.30  1  0    4    4
# 3 17.8   6 167.6 123 3.92 3.44 18.90  1  0    4    4
# 4 16.4   8 275.8 180 3.07 4.07 17.40  0  0    3    3
# 5 17.3   8 275.8 180 3.07 3.73 17.60  0  0    3    3
# 6 15.2   8 275.8 180 3.07 3.78 18.00  0  0    3    3
```

Comment: Sorry for the confusion.  In the bottom code from my original post, I believe what I did was that I exported all rows into an empty directory.  From there what I want to do is build a loop so that I can scan a folder, which includes all rows and column names and create a new data frame (this was my attempt with the code above that one).  I think the problem with my current code is that it only works for columns but I want to get columns and rows.

Comment: I reordered the paragraphs.  Hope this helps.

Comment: I don't understand how that works with both row and columns at the same time. Do you then have a single datum (i.e. an single entry or a 1 by 1 data.frame) in each file? Please try to correct or modify your minimal example to accurately reflect your problem.

Comment: In each file I have one row.  This is produced by the first code or what you wrote as the "minimal example".  The number of files corresponds to the number of rows.

Comment: Right, I understand that---and the code I wrote finds all `.txt` files in the working directory (the folder), reads the rows, and then combines these rows into a single `data.frame`.  So, as far as I can tell, that seems to be what you ask when you say *"What I want to do is to build a loop so that I can scan a folder, which includes all rows and column names and create a new data frame."*  However it is done without using a `for`-loop. If this is not what you expect, please explain **precisely** what you want as the output?

Comment: I guess this would seem like a quick way but how would you do this in terms of a loop?  Most importantly want to know how I can modify my second code.  As the output I would like to see a new data frame, exactly like what you produced above.  I guess putting it into a loop type of code helps me think more logically.

Comment: I don't want to just take your solution, know that it works and call it a day.

Comment: @cambelot Ok, I've edited the answer to use a for loop. It's hard to modify your second piece of code as I cannot run it (I don't have your files).